# BlackBerry application freezes on OS 6 using LocationListener

Tags: java, blackberry, gps, location

I have a Java Application that uses the **LocationProvider** API to register a **LocationListener** at startup of the application and deregisters it when closing the application. It does so too when putting the application in the background and getting it back to the foreground.

This works quite well in most cases but I am experiencing **freezes/hangs** of the app lately on different devices (eg I could reproduce it on my BlackBerry Torch OS 6, seems like it happens more often on OS 6 devices).

I **open** the app, **close it**, **reopen** it and it **freezes** when I try to **close it again**. I can not close it anymore. I have to use the "switch application" functionality go to another app (by holding the Menu button or pressing the green or red button).

After I while I get an error message saying that the application did not respond and was closed.

The code looks like the following:

```
public void activate() {
    if (ApplicationPermissionsManager.getInstance().getPermission(14) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) {
        startLocationProvider();
    }
}

public void deactivate() {
    if (ApplicationPermissionsManager.getInstance().getPermission(14) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) {
        stopLocationProvider();
    }
}

public boolean onClose() {
    stopLocationProvider();
    System.exit(0);
    return true;
}

public void startLocationProvider() {
  try {
    locationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance(new BlackBerryCriteria(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_ASSIST));
    if (locationProvider != null) {
      locationProvider.setLocationListener(new LocationListenerImpl(), 10, 9, -1);
    }
  } catch (Exception le) {
    // log it           
  }
}

public void stopLocationProvider() {
  if (locationProvider != null) {
    try {
      locationProvider.setLocationListener(null, -1, -1, -1);
      locationProvider = null;
    } catch (Exception se) {
      // log it             
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: we are experiencing similar issue, the app work great on OS5 but freezes on OS6. we tried to compile the app on a OS6 SDK, it rans OK on OS6 simulator but when we ran it on a OS device on a Blackberry Network (3G BB) it freezes. Have you found a solution?
I would love to find out the fix thanks

Answer (score 1):

The location listener (which you don't provide code for) is called on the event thread. If a method invoked on the event thread blocks for too long it causes the hanging you are experiencing. The OS will eventually kill such applications for failing to respond. You need to look for segments of LocationListenerImpl that could take a long time to execute, or post that code so we can have a look at it.